# Why did I not get a half-bounty?

Tags: support

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/668566/how-do-i-prevent-ati-graphics-card-from-over-heating/673028#673028) had a bounty. The grace period expired and the bounty disappeared.

I have a +4 answer there and as far as I know I was supposed to get a half-bounty.

This is not a rant. I know this answer is not worth it, but I am just curious.

Comment: were the votes acquired during the bounty period?

Comment: Yes, It was already +4 a few days.

Comment: before the bounty started?

Comment: 3 upvotes happened after the bounty was started.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that I know the reason.

The answer was posted before the bounty started.

It does not matter when it was upvoted.

Half-bounties are awarded only for answers posted after the bounty starts.

Comment: Are you not going to accept this answer?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Thought it needed a day or 12 hours or w/e to accept ones own answer?

Comment: @ThomasW.: Oh, I forgot about the 2 day wait...

Comment: This is correct.